# Swift: Efficiency considerations of shuffling an array of strings

Tags: swift, string, processing-efficiency

If I have an array of strings `["xyz", "def", ...]` in Swift how is this list stored?

My plan is to shuffle this array by transposing random pairs of elements.

Does the array contain a list of pointers to the Strings which I can just swap at minimal cost?

In other words if I shuffle the array in this way, will it just swap  the pointers or will this approach cause it to copy the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason not to use the built-in [`Array.shuffled()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/shuffled())? You can implement your own [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) or whatever, but the built-in one is simple, well-optimized, and well, built-in!

```swift
let fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print(fruits.shuffled())
```

In your own algorithms, you can use [`Array.swapAt(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/swapat(_:_:)) to swap the elements at any two indices in an array.

## Storage details

For your own curiousity, I'll give a bit of detail on how these things are stored. For Arrays and Strings... its complicated. Both are open source, so you can see for yourself:

- [`stdlib/public/core/Array.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift)
- [`stdlib/public/core/String.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/String.swift)

Each of them multiple storage strategies to optimize certain cases. For example:

- `Array` can be backed by an `NSArray` for fast, copy-less bridging to-from Objective-C.
- Likewise for `String` and `NSString`.
- Native Swift Arrays store `struct`s like strings directly inline in a contiguous buffer.

Strings are currently usually a 16 byte struct that contains a pointer to a heap-allocated storage. There's a small-string optimization that forgoes that heap allocation, if the string content is 15 bytes or less, where it will just store it directly inline.

Comment: Great answer. (Voted.)

Comment: Yes there is a good reason I can't use Array.shuffled().  However for posterity and for people who just need a regular shuffle, I'm going to mark that as the answer. Thanks for the background info on the storage strategies, very informative!

Comment: I’m curious, what’s the reason?

Comment: The reason I can't just use `Array.shuffle()` is that the shuffling is not uniform. Right now I'm sorting the names of image files for a slideshow.  I want some randomness but I still want the images to group by location and time to some extent.  For this reason I need tighter control than just a plain shuffle.

Comment: @pnadeau ah yeah. So I guess you’re looking for something like this? https://engineering.atspotify.com/2014/02/how-to-shuffle-songs/

Comment: Yes thx for that link.  In this case I want to sort of do an similar thing, except it's sort of inverted.  I want related images to cluster together most of the time with some exceptions.  Thanks for the link, I think it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can look with "jump to definition" that Strings and Arrays are `Struct`. They are value types. But it doesn't mean that they storing all content in the stack, they have pointer inside that pointing to heap. You can think of them as smart pointers.
If task to work with large memory and performance is significantly important, then better to look for more low level programming language.